# Check if one string contains another, smaller string

Tags: php, regex, string

If I have two PHP variables that are strings and one is a multi-word string while the other is a single-word string.

How can I write a custom function that returns true if the larger string contains the smaller string.

Here is what I have so far in terms of code:

```
function contains($smaller, $larger){
    //if $smaller is in larger{
        return true;
    }
    else{
         return false;

}
```

How can I do the commented out part?

I can't use a regex since I don't know the exact value of $smaller, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version should return a Boolean and guard against 0 vs false return

```
function contains($smaller, $larger){
   return strpos($larger, $smaller) !== false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a php function strstr which will return the position of the "smaller" string.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

```
if(strstr($smaller, $larger)) 
{
     //Its true
}
```

Comment: I don't want to know the position. Just if it exists in `$larger`. So can I just put a `return true;` inside the if's suite?

Comment: Anything over 1 is true, so if there is no position its 0 or false.  You don't need a function to do this... just use my code above and it will work. So don't send it to your function, just use strstr and pass it your two words it will work exactly the way you want.

Comment: However, to answer your question, Yes... it will work if you return true of false,  you just don't need to.  instead of saying:
if(contains($smaller, $larger)) just say if(strstr($smaller, $larger))

Comment: everything over 1 is true, so 2 is true 1 is false?
@Django go to the php link and check an example..

Comment: one is not false. however 0 will be converted to false in an if statement I beleive.  orangePill's answer is the best here.

Answer (score 2):

PHP already has it. Strpos is your answer

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

```
if (strpos($larger, $smaller) !== false){
  // smaller string is in larger
} else {
  // does not contains
}
```

If it founds the string, it returns the position. Beware to check for 0 (if the position of a smaller is in the 0-th location)

Comment: I don't want to know the position. Just if it is in `$larger` or not. What is the value if it is not found? Can I do if the value is 0 or higher than return true, if the value if the smaller string is not found then return false?

Comment: its 0 when the position is 0 and false when it's not within the string. (0 == false) == true but (0 === false) == false